# Microsoft.Moles.vshost has stopped working

Tags: moles

I have a bunch of unit tests written in C# that use moles for mocking a serial port class.  I'm using Visual Studio 2008.  This has all worked fine until today when I went to re-run the tests... and as soon as it tries to create an MSerialPort object, the warning box pops up with  the message "Microsoft.Moles.VsHost has stopped working".  I've tried re installing moles, etc but not sure what else to try or where to find more information on this.  None of the tests themselves have changed so it's got to be something with the .net runtime or the like.  I'm using .net 3.5.  Anyone else run into something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem... something about security update KB2742599 (security update to .NET 3.5) broke moles.  I uninstalled this update, restarted the PC, and everything works fine again.  I'm using windows 7 SP1, x86.