# VS2008 Microsoft.Moles.VsHost stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mstest, moles

I had a solution with the unit tests for MSTest with Moles 0.94.51023.0 working fine under VS2010 IDE.  Had to downgrade the solution to VS2008 SP1.  All tests without moles work fine. Every test with moles throws "Microsoft.Moles.VSHost has stopped working" error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had found the similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983541/microsoft-moles-vshost-has-stopped-working).

Apparently Microsoft Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2742599) prevents MSTest in VS2008 from working with Moles.  As soon as I removed this update, the tests with Moles start working.